# Can we pass table column info to help FormParser determine header_row contents?

Tags: cloud-document-ai

Suppose I have a pdf file containing the following table info

Trainer: Giannis

Pokedex: Incomplete

| Name | Type | Weight | Height | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pikachu | Electric | 6.0 kg | 0.4 m | Yellow |
| Bulbasaur | Grass/Poison | 6.9 kg | 0.7 m | Green |
| Charizard | Fire/Flying | 90.5 kg | 1.7 m | Orange |
| Jigglypuff | Normal/Fairy | 5.5 kg | 0.5 m | Pink |
| Gyarados | Water/Flying | 235.0 kg | 6.5 m | Blue |

I am using the [Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) to extract the table information.

If I know that the table columns will always be `[Name, Type, ... , Color]` is there a way to pass this info to the `FormParser` processor to help it better determine the header rows?

Thank u in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add any "hints" for the Form Parser to adjust the model at this time. You can try using a [different version](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser:%7E:text=pretrained%2Dform%2Dparser%2Dv1.0%2D2020%2D09%2D23) of the Form Parser model to see if the results are more like what you would expect.

To extract values from a document using a custom defined schema like you are suggesting, you will likely get the best results using a [Custom Document Extractor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_cde). You can follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-processor) for instructions on how to build a custom processor, and [this section about Quick Tables](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/label-documents#quick_tables) in the labeling documentation could be useful to speed up labeling for tabular data.

Comment: Thank you very much Holt! 
Also your video guides about documentai are amazing !